# Are EJBs applications like Web Services?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, ejb

Is developping an EJB application is considered like a web services ?

Or the two are different ?

Or you can make EJBs like web services ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer would be yes and no.

**No** in the sense that EJB is a *programming model*. This programming model contains concepts such as security, transaction demarcation, state management and persistency (stateful or stateless beans), and more. While web service is more a *remoting technology*, that is, a way to connect systems, which is SOAP in the case of web service. Under this perspective both are completely different topic (Web service could be compared to RMI-IIOP though).

**Yes** in the sense that both are usually referred as technologies to expose a service to the outside (as long as it's stateless). Under this perspective they belong to the same category. And an EJB can indeed be exposed very easily as a web service by annotating the bean accordingly.

Hope it brings some light to the distinction.

Comment: I did understand your "yes", but not your "no". Can you tell me more the differences between "remoting technology" and "programming model". because to me, they seem the same.

Comment: You design a solution so that it matches/leverages a programming model (examples: EJB, ASP.NET, Servlets, CORBA, maybe even MapReduce, etc.) A remoting technology is just a standard to exchange/marshal data (examples: SOAP, RMI, IIOP, JSON, etc.). The term web service is actually vague and can be seen as a bit of both.

Answer (score 0):

An EJB is an object that has some useful methods, typically Business Logic, and those methods can be invoked by clients in a number of ways - one of those ways can be a Web Service interface.

In  development terms it's pretty much just a matter of annotating the EJB with your chosen interfaces style.

Putting the logic in an EJB can be a good idea because you get easy control over Transactional behaviour, declarative Security and scalability from the EJB container.